# Did Light know L's real name?

Tags: death-note

In *Death Note*, Light picked up Rem's notebook after he/she died by writing L's name in the notebook.

Does it mean that Light knew L's real name, after that?

Comment: The part of the answer that matters on SE was given by yourself, the rest is speculation. He had the means to learn the name. Did he read the names written by Rem? That's speculation territory. (But obviously, he did! Light would never give up on information.)

Comment: It's likely that he did as he had access to the death note left by Rem, but whether he did learn it or not is not important to the rest of the story, nor it is officially revealed.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe he did not bother checking his rival's name or something. I guess he saw the name, but maybe it was of no significance to him. Also, in one of the early episodes, Light says that he is terrible with names and faces.

So most probably, he saw the name but forgot it, or he saw it but it was not revealed to us whether he now knew his actual name or not, or he simply didn't bother to check his name.